# What is the build number of SQL Server 2008 Web Edition that RTMed?

Tags: sql-server

My title is the full question: What is the build number of SQL Server 2008 Web Edition that RTMed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT @@VERSION

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (X64)
```

Comment: So does that mean that 1600 is the build number?

Comment: Yes. 10 is the major version.